# Can not override login and register template FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override the `login.html.twig` template to use it inside a `content` block on `base.html.twig`. For that I create a structure as image shows under `app/Resources`:

[image: 7-1-2014 6-42-33 pm]

When I access `http://myapp/web/app_dev.php/login` I see the default FOSUserBundle login form I mean without styles, images and so on even when this is the code I have in `login.html.twig`:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}
        adasdasdasd
    {% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

what I'm doing wrong? What I miss from docs? `base.html.twig` is the default layout under `app/Resources/views` as may notice on the same image. I'm using Symfony 2.5 (old directory structure) and FOSUserBundle 2.0@dev (friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev)

Comment: Your folder structure looks correct so I assume it's a template extension issue. Have you extended the correct templates? Please post some code to show the structure of your login.html.twig file.

Comment: @orciny I added some info to main post, take a look, the funny part is that even `base.html.twig` styles, images and so on doesn't appears to and yes I clear the cache several times by running `cache:clear` and `cache:warmup` commands and also by hand `rm -r app/cache`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle override directory should be:

app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/

It looks like you have the bundle directory nested too deep.

Comment: You're right I spent few hours without get the mistake, four eyes seen more than two, thanks man!